# Showing that $v$ also satisfied the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose $u(x,t)$ satisfies the wave equation
$$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$$
for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha \ne 0$ be a constant, and define
$$v(x,t) = u(\alpha x, \alpha t)$$
Show that $v$ also satisfies the wave equation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried?

Comment: Just substitute that in to the wave equation.  What do you get?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think I am not understanding the question from the start - Does $u$ = $u(x,t)$?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this type of transformation is called dilation. By the chain rule, 
$$v_{tt}(x,t) = \alpha^2u_{tt}(\alpha x,\alpha t)$$
and similarly,
$$v_{xx}(x,t) = \alpha^2u_{xx}(\alpha x,\alpha t).$$ 
It follows that
$$
v_{tt}(x,t) - c^2v_{xx}(x,t) = \alpha^2(u_{tt}(\alpha x,\alpha t) - c^2u_{xx}(\alpha x, \alpha t)) = \alpha^2\cdot0 = 0.
$$
Hence, $v$ satisfies the wave equation. Having seen this, it may be good practice to show that $v(x,t) = u(x - \alpha,t)$ also satisfies the wave equation.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand that $v_{tt}$ and $v_{xx}$ are taking the form from the original equation $u_{tt}$ and $u_{xx}$. But when you are using the chain rule, why is $\alpha$ taken to the second power?

Comment: Also, how do you get $\alpha^2\cdot0 = 0$ in the last equation? How do you get that it becomes multiplied by zero?

Comment: To answer your first question, the $\alpha^2$ comes from taking two derivatives. In regards to the second, notice that $u_{tt}(\alpha x, \alpha t) - c^2 u_{xx}(\alpha x, \alpha t) = 0$ since $u$ is a solution to the wave equation. This becomes more clear after a variable substitution $y = \alpha x$ and $s = \alpha t$.